# Are there issues with caching / reusing a RxBleDevice instance?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

`RxBleClient#scanBleDevices` emits a sequence of `ScanResult` objects.  In turn, `ScanResult#getBleDevice` provides the `RxBleDevice` instance from one of these emitted item.

Are there any issues with caching a `RxBleDevice` instance to avoid having to perform future scans?

A couple of potential use cases:

- A scan is performed well ahead of the need to actually connect to the device.
- A general scan is performed for an unrelated operation, so it would be efficient to utilize any other devices emitted during this scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options:

- You can cache `RxBleDevice` instance yourself, as long as you keep the client instance. It internally keeps some references to objects scoped with the lifecycle of the client.
- You can use `RxBleClient#getBleDevice` passing the MAC address. `RxBleDevice` instances are cached across the client and you shouldn't expect performance issues with creating the device.

Comment: It is worth noting that some implementations of the BLE stack (i.e. Samsung's) do not connect successfuly to a device created before the `BluetoothAdapter` was turned on. In other words-after the bluetooth is turned on one must first re-scan the device before the connection will be established (even if the device was successfuly scanned before the adapter was turned off). If it won't happen `status=133` is usually returned in `BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply @pawel.urban.  actually, we already are caching the MAC address once we have found the device in a scan, so we can continue our existing approach to use `RxBleClient#getDevice(MACAddr)`.  great to know we'll get the same benefits as if we cached the `RxBleDevice`.

Comment: interesting information @DariuszSeweryn.  we had been seeing some odd behavior with inability to connect to devices after they have been previously found.  i hadn't been able to find the root cause.  perhaps this is a result of the of what you describe.  i am going to investigate invalidating our MAC Addr cache whenever bluetooth changes state.